# Sending sensor data via UDP

Tags: arduino, udp, declaration, send

I'm trying to send sensor data via UDP. At the moment I'm struggling with the "packing" of the UDP packets. It says "incomingData" is not declared when I try to send it.
I would appreciate any kind of advice. 
Code below.
Thank you :)

```
//Version 1.012

//necessary libraries
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet2.h>
#include <EthernetUdp2.h>

//Pin settings
#define CTD 19

//Network Settings
byte mac[] = { 0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x10, 0xEC, 0xAB };  //set MAC Address Ethernet Shield (Backside)
byte ip[]  = { XXX, XXX, X, X };                      //set IP-Address
byte gateway[] = { XXX, XXX, X, X };                  //set Gateway
byte subnet[]  = { 255, 255, 255, 1 };                //set Subnetmask


//local UDP port to listen on
unsigned int localPort = 4000;

//Recipient IP
IPAddress RecipientIP(127, 0, 0, 1);

//Recipient UDP port
unsigned int RecipientPort = 4444;

//Buffer for sending data
char packetBuffer[UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE];

//EthernetUDP instance
EthernetUDP Udp;



void setup()
{
   //Start Ethernet
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  //Start UDP
  Udp.begin(localPort);

  //for debug only
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Serial baud rate for CTD
  Serial1.begin(1200);

  //Version 1.012
Serial.print("Version 1.012");

  //CTD
  pinMode(CTD, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{

//If CTD is sending
if (Serial1.available())
{
  //read incoming data
  int incomingData = Serial1.read();

  //for debug only
  Serial.print("Data: ");
  Serial.println(incomingData, BIN);
}

//Send UDP packets
int packetSize = Udp.parsePacket();
  if (packetSize) {

    // read the packet into packetBufffer
    Udp.read(packetBuffer, UDP_TX_PACKET_MAX_SIZE);

    // send to the IP address and port
    Udp.beginPacket(Udp.remoteIP(), Udp.remotePort());
    Udp.write(incomingData);
    Udp.endPacket();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the if `(packetSize)` is exexuted first before `if (Serial1.available())` when you try to send data and thus `incomingData` is not getting declared but you are trying to use it inside `if (packetSize)`.Thus you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you have declared  `incomingData` as `int` inside `void loop ()` function inside `if (Serial1.available())` .

But if the above if loop  fails the `incomingData` will not be declared and say  `packetsize` is greater than zero ( packet available) then `if (packetSize)` segment will be executed.Thus `incomingData` is not declared but it is used .That's why you get the error you stated.

Comment: Make `incomingData` global and check it.

Comment: Isn't it helpful

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
 

Thank you for your advice. This definitely makes sense ;)

I'm still struggling with the Transmission of the UDP packets. I'm using "Wireshark" as a control for incoming packets. The IP adress of the UDP packet is my fixed PC's configured IP right? I changed my script but I still don't receive any packages :/

Thanks!

Here's my code:  0
down vote
accept
 

@Billa Thank you for your advice. This definitely makes sense ;)  I'm still struggling with the Transmission of the UDP packets. I'm using "Wireshark" as a control for incoming packets.